# Reading lines of a "text" file using fscanf() on cygwin

Tags: c, windows, file-io, cygwin

Consider this code:

```
FILE * fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
int ret = fscanf(fp, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
if (ret != 5)
{
    // error and exit
}
long file_pos = ftell(fp);
printf("file position: %ld\n", file_pos);
```

The line of file being read is:

```
6, 5, 3, 2, 6\r\n
```

That is, the file has Windows line endings.

The file position comes out to be 20, whereas I expected it to be 15.
However, if I change the file open mode to binary (`"rb"`), the file position is 15, as expected.

After googling this up I could not find any clue as to why this is happening, but only found that people suggest not using fscanf() ever.

But I would like to know why the file pointer is not where it should be.

Comment: Can you just read in and print out the first 20 or 24 bytes of the file (opened with `"r"`) and print them out to see what those bytes are?

Comment: Are there additional blank lines after the first that might be being chomped by the `\n` at the end of the format string?

Comment: @DanielFischer: The contents are OK. But further parsing goes awry. Not so with `rb`

Comment: @twalberg: No there are no blank lines after the first.

Comment: @puffadder The question is, what are these bytes? If the first 15 are exactly "6, 5, 3, 2, 6\r\n", what are the next ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscanf may be buffering the file - ie it reads a certain sized block and then parses it to decode the contents.

Comment: But why does buffer/no buffer decision depend on the file open mode?

Comment: @puffadder fscanf makes no guarantees about what it does internally to read the file - you might find that it pre-reads a different number of bytes on a different version of Windows.

Comment: Does that mean that if I read first line with fscanf() and the successive lines with fgets() + sscanf(), I could be in for a surprise?

Comment: @puffadder if you mix fscanf() and fgets() then odd things can happen